# Can i stop an if statement from running multiple times when condition is true (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a clicker game and add an achievement where when you go past a certain number it gives the achievement, but after you go past it gives the achievement every click. Is there a way i can fix this?

```
def clicks():
global x
global y
x = x+y
print(x,"clicks")


#1000 cookies
if x >= 1000:
    print('Achievement Unlocked: Clicker Beginner! (Achievement 1/7)')
```

Comment: why not if x==1000:

Comment: Introduce a variable / flag `aready_achieved` which you set and check accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `boolean` flag like `achievementGranted` and set it as `true` when you add achievement.

Also maybe more useful and secure to use `if x == 1000`? Because this statement will be executed once when x == 1000, not every time when x >= 1000

Answer (score 0):

```
def clicks():
   global x
   global y
   x = x+y
print(x,"clicks")


#1000 cookies
if x == 1000:
    print('Achievement Unlocked: Clicker Beginner! (Achievement 1/7)')
```

You also need to indent the things after def as I've done above

Answer (score 0):

Your condition say: **if x>=** so that mean even when c become 1001 it will work

Should be only **==** and you can store the value to use it in another place

Comment: It won`t work when there will be 1000 cookies two or more times (ex. you buy smth and you have left 1000 cookies and you have achievement one more time)

Comment: Inside the function you can but condition to rest x each time become bigger than 1000

Comment: Also store how many time x was rested, to calculate achievement number based on it, and leave the outside condition x ==1000